# Get item from PHP array without loop

Tags: php, arrays

In JavaScript, if I have object or array from JSON

```
var arr = ["one", "two", "three"];
var obj = {"hello": "dolly", "jurassic": "park"}
```

I can get any individual item from it easily without looping:

```
alert(arr[1]); // outputs "two"
alert(obj["hello"]); // outputs "dolly"
```

Is there a similar way to do this in PHP?

```
echo arr[1];
echo obj["hello"];
echo arr->1
echo obj->"hello"
```

Comment: It's the same for php, just write the array iin php format and the variables too

Comment: Ok, I must have had a syntax error, because it's working now. Dangit. Thanks for the sanity check. Let's delete this embarrassment of a question.

Comment: There you dont has a nested array...

Comment: Question was based on an unknown syntactical error.

Comment: this is a nested array $array = array(
    "one"=>array(
        "hello" => "dolly", 
        "jurassic" => "park"
        ),
    "two"=>array(
        "hello" => "dolly2", 
        "jurassic" => "park2"
        ), 
    "three"=>array(
        "hello" => "dolly3",
        "jurassic" => "park3"
        )
    );

echo $array['one']['hello']; //print dolly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fairly explanatory:

```
php > $arr = json_decode('["one","two","three"]');
php > echo $arr[2];
three
php > $obj = (array) json_decode('{"hello":"dolly","jurassic":"park"}');
php > echo $obj["hello"];
dolly
php > $obj = json_decode('{"hello":"dolly","jurassic":"park"}');
php > echo $obj->hello;
dolly
```

Answer (score 3):

In PHP, it is exactly the same.

**Javascript**

```
var foo = ['bar', 'baz', 'quux'];
console.log(foo[1]);
var q = { key: 'value', otherkey: 'othervalue' };
console.log(q['value']);
```

**PHP**

```
$foo = array('bar', 'baz', 'quux');
echo $foo[1]; // prints "baz"
$q = array('key' => 'value', 'otherkey' => 'othervalue');
echo $q['key']; // prints 'value'
```

Answer (score 2):

In php:

```
$arr = array("one", "two", "three");
$obj = array("hello" => "dolly", "jurassic" => "park");


 echo $arr[1];// print two
 echo $obj["hello"]; // print dolly
```

Remember that the array start from index zero

[PHP Array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)